# Why do u,v components in Cauchy-Riemann conditions are irrotational?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

It's very strange to me! When we decompose a complex function to a real part and an immaginary part, we have

$f(z) = u(x,y) + j v(x,y)$

following the conditions of analyticity we can derive the Cauchy-Riemann conditions where

1. $u_x$ = $v_y$
2. $v_x$ = -$u_y$

I see that my text book says that these components are irrotational while I see that it depends. When I calculate the curl I see:

Curl = 0 + 0 + ($v_x$ - $u_y$) = 2 * $v_x$

I see that if we consider u the second and v the first component it will be irrotational but in the default order the thing that I'd expected to work the curl doesn't appear to be 0. What is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector field $\vec f(x,y)$ that corresponds to the complex function $f(z)$ has a sign change on the $y$-component.  That is,

$$\vec f(x,y) = u(x,y) \hat x - v(x,y) \hat y$$

The curl and divergence of this vector field are zero as a consequence of the Cauchy-Riemann conditions.  In vector fields that are divergenceless and curlless* are fully determined by their values on some bounding surface (or a hypersurface beyond 3d), just as 2d holomorphic functions are fully determined by their values on some closed curve.

*Curl doesn't exist beyond 3d, but there are ways to generalize it, and it's not a crime to call these generalizations "curl" also.

---

Edit: now why should there be a sign change?  Well, you could identify it by inspection, but that's a pretty unsatisfying answer.  A better (though more complicated) one is to *construct* a correspondence between complex functions and vector fields.  You can do that if they're both algebraic elements of the same algebra--a "clifford" algebra.

Clifford algebra works with a noncommutative product called the *geometric product*.  A 2d clifford algebra can be built from four basis elements:  call them $1, e_1, e_2, e_1 e_2$.  Basically, the multiplication works like so:  $e_1 e_1 = e_2 e_2 = 1$ (so it captures the dot product), and $e_1 e_2 = -e_2 e_1$ (so for orthogonal vectors, it anticommutes like the cross product), and $e_1 e_1 e_2 = (e_1 e_1) e_2 = e_2$, so it's associative.

Now, how does this all connect to complex numbers?  As it turns out, the object $e_1 e_2$ has a special property:

$$(e_1 e_2)^2 = e_1 e_2 e_1 e_2 = -e_1 e_1 e_2 e_2 = -1$$

So algebraically, $e_1 e_2$ behaves exactly like the imaginary unit, $j$!  The algebra of linear combinations $a + b e_1 e_2$ for real numbers $a, b$ is exactly the algebra of complex numbers.

But!  We have the extra benefit of still having $e_1, e_2$ around as basis vectors.  Vectors *coexist* alongside these complex numbers.  Indeed, you can take a position vector $x e_1 + y e_2$ and convert it to a complex number by multiplying on the left by $e_1$:

$$e_1 (x e_1 + y e_2) = x + y e_1 e_2$$

So, this demands the question why we can't do this for vector fields.  The answer comes from differentiation, from the use of $\nabla$.  Consider a function $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + e_1 e_2 v(x,y)$, like your complex function, and let's take a derivative with $\nabla$:

$$\nabla f = e_1 (\partial_x u - \partial_y v) + e_2 (\partial_y u + \partial_x v)$$

The components are those expressions in the Cauchy-Riemann condition, so if $\nabla f = 0$, then the C-R condition holds.

How can we build up a vector field from $f$, though?  We can't do it by multiplying by $e_1$ on the left:  $\nabla$ is in the way, and inserting an $e_1$ between $\nabla$ and $f$ isn't something you can just do whenever you like.

But you *can* multiply by $1 = e_1 e_1$ on the *right*. This gives us the expression $[\nabla (f e_1)] e_1$.  That $f e_1$ evaluates to

$$f e_1 = u e_1 + e_1 e_2 e_1 v = u e_1 - v e_2$$

I have, perhaps, gone a bit too far in trying to give evidence for this mathematical curiosity, but I hope it's piqued your interest.

Comment: So the curl in this question is beyond 3d and that's because the corresponding vector field has a negative sign on y-component? In fact I can't understand why the corresponding vector field must have a sign change on y-component. Especially because j vector is mapped to a positive unit on the y-axis!

Comment: I was saying that, *if* you have a good and proper generalization of the curl that works beyond 3d, then vector fields that are divergenceless and curlless are totally defined by their values on some hypersurface. This applies for all vector fields that obey these two properties. It doesn't really have to do with the sign change. I'll provide an explanation for the sign change shortly, though I fear the kind of math required to make use of it may be a bit unfamiliar.

Comment: thanks a lot, it looked complicated but still beautiful.

Comment: @Muphrid can you tell me any good reference about these discussion?

Comment: @GA316 This is well-developed in the geometric algebra literature (starting with Hestenes in the '70s, not with Artin's book "Geometric Algebra").  *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* touches on this relationship in great detail, particularly with trying to generalize holomorphic functions to vector fields on real vector spaces.